# Add multiple attributes to user account

Tags: powershell, attributes, powershell-cmdlet

Good afternoon,
i've trawled the usual places, here, MS, Scritping guy, Month of lunches etc. to try and answer to my problem.  I have a list of users identified by email address and i would like to change their currently blank attributes with the information below.
so:

- 33 = GLOBAL
- 34 = 4
- 35 = SMTP:User@NewDomain.com

  ```
  Get-ADUser -filter {(Mail -like 'User@OldDomain.com')} -Properties * | Set-ADUser -Replace @{$_.MSExchExtensionAttribute33="GLOBAL"; $_.MSExchExtensionAttribute34="4"; $_.msExchExtensionAttribute35="SMTP:User@NewDomain.com"};
  ```

However, when i run the commands i receive this error:

```
A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... roperties * | Set-ADUser -Add @{$_.MSExchExtensionAttribute34="4"; $_ ...
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collections.Hashtable:Hashtable) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey
```

i've used variations on this code in the past without issue to replace attributes that already have values in place so i wonder if that's part of the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use varations of this code in the same AD ? If not, you might need to create the attribute in AD schema first : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20319.how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Same users, same AD, different attributes.

Comment: Untested, but I think you should leave out the `$_`. Also, it is not a very good idea to ask for ALL properties using the asterisk. Try this: `Get-ADUser -Filter 'mail -like "User@OldDomain.com"' -Properties msExchExtensionAttribute33, msExchExtensionAttribute34, msExchExtensionAttribute35 | Set-ADUser -Replace @{msExchExtensionAttribute33="GLOBAL"; msExchExtensionAttribute34="4"; msExchExtensionAttribute35="SMTP:User@NewDomain.com"}
`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for changing a (custom) attribute is

`Set-ADUser $userName -add @{'MSExchExtensionAttribute33'="Global"}`

I hope this solves the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Like @theo suggested: leave out the $_ variable, and additionally: requesting properties is not needed at all when setting them. So try this, it works on my machine:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {(Mail -like 'User@OldDomain.com')} | 
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{MSExchExtensionAttribute33="GLOBAL"; MSExchExtensionAttribute34="4"; msExchExtensionAttribute35="SMTP:User@NewDomain.com"}
```